# Graph traversal with Multiple nodes

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree

I recently had an interview that I failed and have been thinking about the question since then. I would really appreciate some help in figuring out how to solve it.

Given the employees that came organically and the employees that were referred by someone. Find the employee with the longest chain of referrals.

Ex: If A came organically and they referred C and C referred D.
If B came organically and B referred F. Result will be A.

I don't remember the original data structure but the interviewer suggested to make an agency list so let's pick up from there.

```
map = {
A: C
C: D
B: F
}
```

How will we iterate this list? Is it as simple as keeping the order of inputs and a counter for each vertex?

Here's my shot at the solution (pseudo code):

```
int countReferrals(employee, map, int& last_index){
    if(!map.find(employee)){
     //no referrals hired by this employee
     return 0;
    }
    last_index++;
    int count_referred = 1 + countReferrals(map.find(employee)->second, map, last_index);
    return count_referred;
}

employee mostReferrals(map){
   int last_index = 0;   // first index to start iterating
   int most = 0;
   employee most_refs = map[0];
   while(last_index < map.size()){
      employee curr_empl = map[last_index];
      int curr_refs = countReferrals(map[last_index], map, last_index);
      if(most<curr_refs){
         most = curr_refs;
         most_refs = curr_empl;
      }
      
   }
   return most_refs;
}
```

I am not even sure what is the best data structure for this? I just used map because it it's the fastest lookup time and I don't know how to keep track of vertex that doesn't have a parent. I am not good with graphs and trees. However I am trying to improve. Am I on the right path here?

Edit:
The example mentioned in the comment makes this graph:

```
           J                    A                Y                
                              / | \             /                 
                            C   E  G           I                  
                          / | \
                         D  H  Z
```

But even if we have a map: list here I am still not sure how to traverse a multi root tree. One other solution I can think of is just having a class:

```
Class tree {
  char value;
  vector<char> children;
}
```

And we can have a vector of all the employees that came organically.
Then to find the employee with most referrals we just have to return the tree with max size i.e. size of children + size of children of children.

Comment: "agency list" should be "adjacency list". Each entry in `map` should be one-to-many, e.g. `A:[C,E,G]` means that A referred C, E, and G. The data represents a tree, where the root connects to the organic employees, and the child nodes of an employee are the referrals.

Comment: Thank you, I am not able to complete understand what you mean by "The data represents a tree, where the root connects to the organic employees". How will we represent employees referred by a referred employee using an agency list.
Continuing your example if C referred D, H, Z and Y referred I and J referred no one. 
```
A: [C, E, G]
C: [D, H, Z]
Y: [I]
J: []
```
In case this case we have multiple organic employees, so the tree will have multiple roots, how can we traverse such tree? It will be helpful to see some pseudo code to clearly understand what you're suggesting.

Comment: The solution you describe in the edit should work.